# An error in multiple auth for two tables using laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

[image: The error when i login as Admin]

I have two tables one is Normal user And other is for Branch. when i am login as Normal user the its login without any error. Secondly I want to Login Admin with the branch Email and password and it save in branch table but when i login it show an error.

BranchController:

```
public function ggetlogin()
{
    return view('branch_admin.badmin');
}

public function authenticateBranchAdmin(Request $request){
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required'
    ]);

    if($validator->passes()){
        if(Auth::guard('admin')->attempt([
            'email' =>  $request->email,
            'password'  =>  $request->password,
        ])){
            if(Auth::guard('admin')->branch()->email === $request->email){
                return redirect('/branch/'.Branch::branch()->id);
            }

        }else{
            if($this->AdminIsVerified($request->email)){
                $request->session()->flash('message', 'Invalid email or password');
            }
            return redirect('/Admin/login');
        }
    }else{
        return redirect('/Admin/login')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }
}
```

AddBranchView:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
<form class="form-horizontal branch-form" action="/add/branch" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">BranchName</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name">
            @if($errors->has('name'))
                {{$errors->first('name')}}
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">B_Email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email">
            @if($errors->has('email'))
                {{$errors->first('email')}}
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Password</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="password">
            @if($errors->has('password'))
                {{$errors->first('password')}}
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>

        @if(Session::has('message'))
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">{{Session::get('message')}}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endif

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <button type="submit" value="add branch" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{csrf_field()}}
</form>
</div>
```

Auth.php

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'admin'=> [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'branch',
    ],
],
```

Providers:

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,

    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Branch::class,
    ],
],
```

LoginView:

```
<form class="form-horizontal login-form" action="/Admin/login" method="post">

    <div class="form-group" >
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">EMAIL</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email">
            @if($errors->has('email'))
                {{$errors->first('email')}}
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">PASSWORD</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">
            @if($errors->has('password'))
                {{$errors->first('password')}}
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <button type="submit" value="login" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    {{csrf_field()}}
</form>
```

Comment: Can you add `providers` array in your auth.php ?

Comment: yes i add providers array

Comment: Please, do add it into your post so I can see.

Comment: see the providers array

Answer (score 0):

`guards.admin` is looking for a `provider` called *branch*
 You need to have a `branch` in your providers array.

So your `auth.php` should look like:

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'admin'=> [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'branch', // This one says there should be a branch in providers
    ],
],
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,

    'branch' => [ // This is where guards.admin is looking
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Branch::class,
    ],
],
```

Also your Branch model must implement Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable
If your Branch table has the same db colums like, `id`, `password` and `remember_token`; the easiest way would be as same as the User model.

```
namespace App;
//...
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
//...

class Branch extends Authenticatable
{
   //...
}
```

Then you can retrieve your branch as:

```
Auth::guard('admin')->user()->email
```

Plese note that you need to use `user()` to get your branch object. not <s>`branch()`</s>.

---

I'd recommend you to utilize middlewares instead of code in your controller methods. Its more manageable and much easier.

`routes/web.php`

```
Route::get('/some-page-for-normal-users', "AController@index")->middleware('auth:web');

Route::get('/some-page-for-branch-users', "BController@index")->middleware('auth:admin');
```

Then anywhere in your views etc. You will be able to user auth()->user() to get your Branch or User whichever is set in your middleware.